# RegEx to match e-mails also matches URLs

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to code a RegEx that will extract e-mails that come in many forms:

user@domain.com , user@sub.domain.com, user at domain dot com, user (at) domain dot com

Here is my shot (naive I know):

```
(\w+)\s*(?:@?|(at)?|(\s*at\s*)?|(\(at\))?)\s*(\w+(?:\.|\s*dot\s*)){1,}com
```

Thats matches what I want but it also matches URLs. How to exclude URLs matching?

Comment: Google! It takes less than six seconds to find one `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b` All you have to edit is `@` part with your options.

Comment: @Nishant if he replaced the `?` in that regex with his existing group, he'd be breaking it, too -- one of his larger mistakes is in that section.

Comment: @Nishant True but I want to learn how to make it by hand and reveal my mistakes. I'm not looking for a recipe.

Comment: learning is good. :) I am just hinting towards shorter solution. I think the question is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this element:

```
(?:@?|(at)?|(\s*at\s*)?|(\(at\))?)
```

The short answer is that you have too many `?`s, such that a completely empty string will match several of them, such that no `(at)`, `@` or `at` is necessary to match at all.

Because you're already separating the branches with `|`s, you don't need the `?`s to mark an individual branch as unnecessary -- only one of them needs to match, but that one should be non-optional.

Answer (score 3):

Check this tutorial - [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this part

```
(\w+(?:\.|\s*dot\s*))
```

is responsible for the URL matching.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the non-capture group `(?:@?|(at)?|(\s*at\s*)?|((at))?)`.  With all the `?`s, you've made any match completely optional.  Replace that portion with this:

```
(?:@|at|\(at\))
```